# Error while seeding mongodb using mongoose-seed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, seed, seeding

I have model schema in `./model.js` file

```
const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    filePath: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("ImageSchema", ImageSchema);
```

seed.js

```
seeder.connect(
  "mongoURI",{useUnifiedTopology: true},
  function () {
    seeder.loadModels('./model.js');

    seeder.clearModels(['ImageSchema'], function () {
      seeder.populateModels(data, function () {
        seeder.disconnect();
      });
    });
  }
);

var data = [
    {
        'model': 'ImageSchema',
        'documents': [
            {
                'name': "Image",
                'filePath': "/api/image"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I run seed.js file then it says.
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: modelPaths.forEach is not a function    at Seeder.loadModels`

Later, I got to know from the comment below that `seeder.loadModels()` takes an array of paths and I fixed it. Now another issue. It says, Error: Models not registered in Mongoose: ImageSchema.

MyFolder structure is

```
seeder/
  model.js
  seed.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument of `seeder.loadModels()` is an array of paths. So your code should be:

```
seeder.loadModels(['./model.js']);
```

Comment: Yes I fixed that. Now another issue. It says. Error: Models not registered in Mongoose: ImageSchema

Comment: That's weird. Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the post. Have a look at the last section of the post. They both ```seed.js``` and ```model.js``` are in the same directory ```seeder/```

Comment: I don't see any other problem. Just guess you forgot to save some files.